# Xamarin ios - How can I fit a large image inside a UIScrollView

Tags: c#, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I'm working with Xamarin.iOS implemented in C#. I have a list with images. I'm trying to implement a similar functionality to Facebook or any other photo viewing app. The images are quite large but I would like to scale them so they always fit the bounds of the scrollview - the scrollview fits the screen bounds in this case.

My challenge is :

1. My image fills the whole screen but isn't properly scaled.
2. When I zoom out, I'd like the minimum zoom scale to go back to the original view.

Below is my current code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        //Setting up the scrollView  

        ScrollViewMain.BouncesZoom = false;
        ScrollViewMain.ClipsToBounds = true;
        index = 0;

        AddImageInScrollView(index);

        btnClose.AddTarget (this, new Selector ("MySelector"), UIControlEvent.TouchDown);

        btnPrevious.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            index--;
            if(index < 0)
                index = 0;

            imageView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            AddImageInScrollView(index);

        } ;

        btnNext.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            index++;
            if((nuint)index > Car.allThumbnails.Count-1)
                index = (int)Car.allThumbnails.Count-1;

            imageView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            AddImageInScrollView(index);

        } ;


        var tapGestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer (OnDoubleTap);
            tapGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 2;

        ScrollViewMain.AddGestureRecognizer (tapGestureRecognizer);
}

public void AddImageInScrollView(int index)
    {

        //Setting up the imageView
        imageView = new UIImageView(Car.allThumbnails.GetItem<UIImage>((nuint)index));
        imageView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;


        //Adding the imageView to the scrollView as subView
        ScrollViewMain.AddSubview(imageView);

        ScrollViewMain.DecelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRateFast;

        var scrollViewFrame = ScrollViewMain.Frame;
        var scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.Size.Width / ScrollViewMain.ContentSize.Width;
        var scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.Size.Height / ScrollViewMain.ContentSize.Height;

        ScrollViewMain.ContentSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF((float)ScrollViewMain.Bounds.Size.Width, (float)ScrollViewMain.Bounds.Size.Height);


        var minScale = Math.Min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
//Set the zoom properties
        ScrollViewMain.MaximumZoomScale = 3f;
        ScrollViewMain.MinimumZoomScale = (float)minScale;

        ScrollViewMain.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => {
            return imageView;

        };
        ScrollViewMain.ZoomScale = 1.0f;
        ScrollViewMain.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.SizeToFit();
        ScrollViewMain.ContentSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF((float)imageView.Frame.Size.Width, (float)imageView.Frame.Size.Height);

}
```

**This is what it looks like**

[image: Image In ScrollView]